# HTML How to markup 4 panels in a row for content

Tags: html

I'm abysmal at HTML so looking for some help in recreating the following.  I could do it with a table, but understand that that is a no-no nowadays.  So advice is needed.

[alt text http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/8623/4panel.jpg](http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/8623/4panel.jpg)

What I am wanting to achieve is four fixed size boxes then spread across the page on a single row.  These boxes will have some information in them, possibly text, possibly images and possibly both.

The boxes will be static size, ie I don't want them resizing to fit the width of the browser window.  I'm guessing it probably going to be done with the div tag but I don't have the first clue where to start.

Comment: Saying tables are a no-no is a bit over-simplistic. Unless you're trying to get a bunch of people riled up. ;)

Comment: Eek that wasn't my intention - I had just read that tables should only really be used for tabular data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want something like this (not tested)

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="box1" class="box">
    <!-- your content here -->
  </div>

  <div id="box2" class="box">
    <!-- your content here -->
  </div>

  <div id="box3" class="box">
    <!-- your content here -->
  </div>

  <div id="box4" class="box">
    <!-- your content here -->
  </div>

</div>
```

with the CSS

```
.box{
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#box1{
  margin-left: 0;
}

#wrapper{
  margin: 0 auto;  // Center on the page
  width: 860px;
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of `id` and `class` attributes; especially considering that (in your example) `#wrapper` is the only one you really need.

Comment: I went with belt and braces extensibility over minimalist.  You can remove unneeded mark-up, but as Martin said his HTML was bad I thought I'd make it clear.  The extra box1,bax2 Id's would let you target further styles to each box, for example, giving each a different background color.

Answer (score 2):

You can use four fixed-width/height divs which are all set on `float:left;`.

```
<div class="box">Some content</div>
<div class="box">More content</div>
<div class="box">Maybe an image</div>
<div class="box">Some content and an image</div>
```

with this css:

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not so tricky:

```
<div class="panelwrapper">
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
  <div>Content</div>
</div>
```

That's really all the HTML you should need.

Comment: The extra div is for doing things like keeping the box of panels centered, as well as grouping the panels logically. However, you could do without it (although you would then have to add classes to the divs).

Comment: I'm having difficulty working out the CSS I need for the panelwrapper.